# Comprobar si una cookie ha caducado js

Tags: javascript, cookies, timer

tengo que crear una cookie con un nombre, valor y tiempo de caducidad (yo he utilizado el max-age porque me resulta más cómodo), una vez creada tengo que hacer un timer que compruebe cada x segundos si esa cookie sigue disponible o ha caducado, no me funciona correctamente el timer ya que le establezca el max-age que sea a la cookie salta siempre a los dos o tres segundos, cuando si por ejemplo le pongo el max-age a 10 o a 20 no debería de saltar tan temprano. Adjunto el código de js:

```
let nombre = prompt("Introduce nombre de la cookie: ");
let valor = prompt("Introduce valor de la cookie:");
let caducidad = prompt("Introduce caducidad de la cookie (en 
segundos):");

let cookie1 = document.cookie = nombre +"=" + valor+"; max-age ="+ 
caducidad;


function comprobar(){
if(document.cookie == "max-age= "+0){
    alert("La cookie ha sido eliminada");
    }

}

setTimeout(comprobar,3000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1º) Que me corrijan si me equivoco, pero si mal no recuerdo, las cookies caducadas se eliminan, por tanto, dudo que puedas comprobar si una cookie está eliminada de esa forma.

2º) En tu **if**, al menos el que adjuntas de ejemplo, no estás comparando bien los valores, puesto que estás usando solo un **=**.

3º) Esto último que añado, lo desconozco, pero no sé si el atributo **max-age** se va actualizando de manera descendente como para usarlo como comprobación.

Yo simplemente haría en tu función comprobar:

```
if(!document.cookie["my_cookie"]) alert("La cookie ha sido eliminada");
```